# Issue with running gscam node

Tags: gscam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have ROS Hydro, I am trying to run [gscam](http://wiki.ros.org/gscam) node, I have exported the **GSCAM_CONFIG** but upon running the gscam node I get this error, which seems to be a linking error but I don't know how to resolve it.

```
rosrun gscam gscam

/opt/ros/hydro/lib/gscam/gscam: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libgscam.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPvNS0_6levels5LevelERKSt18basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEPKciSE_
```

Any idea how can I fix it.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/158371/issue-with-running-gscam-node/) by [uyaseen](https://answers.ros.org/users/5164/uyaseen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2014-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That looks like one of the ABI problems that's still lurking in ROS when package versions aren't aligned properly.

Try upgrading to all of the latest packages by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uyaseen](https://answers.ros.org/users/5164/uyaseen/) on 2014-04-28**:
Thanks :)
Upgrading all packages fixed the issue.